# MS Word 2019 Include non-heading levels in table of contents

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I would like to format the table of contents to include categories/topics of the chapters:

```
Table of Contents
Topic Aaa
Heading_1...........1
Heading_2...........2
Topic Bbb
Heading_3...........3
Heading_4...........4
Topic Ccc
Heading_5...........5
Heading_6...........6
```

Here `Topic Aaa`, `Topic Bbb`, and `Topic Ccc` may not appear in the main text, so they are not included as headings. Also, unlike the headings, they do not have a page number to refer to.

I tried to insert it manually into TOC. However, after updating the entire table, `Topic Bbb` and `Topic Ccc` were removed (perhaps it's because they were in the region highlighted grey).

Is it possible to modify the TOC to the one above, and `Topic Bbb` and `Topic Ccc` are not removed after updating the whole table? It is fine if they stay at the same lines after I add new headings and update the table:

```
Table of Contents
Topic Aaa
Heading_1...........1
Heading_2...........2
Topic Bbb
New_Heading_1.......3
Heading_3...........4
Topic Ccc
New_Heading_2.......5
Heading_4...........6
Heading_5...........7
Heading_6...........8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here's how I'd do it, using field codes.

First, make sure that paragraph marks are visible. (On the **Home** tab of the ribbon, in the **Paragraph** group, select **Show/Hide ¶**; or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.)

1. In the **Styles** pane, go through the list of Word's built-in document styles, and choose a **paragraph** style (not a **character** style) that I don't plan to use for anything else in the document. For this example, I've chosen the **No Spacing** style. Alternatively, define a brand-new paragraph style.
2. For each topic description that I need, insert a blank paragraph in a place that reflects its desired location in the TOC, and apply the paragraph style that I chose. So, for your example, I add a **No Spacing** paragraph before the Heading_1, Heading_3, and Heading_5 paragraphs.
3. Place the cursor in the first paragraph that I added, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (that's the letter O, not a zero).
4. In the **Mark Table of Contents Entry** dialog box, in the **Entry** field, enter the topic description that I want to appear in the TOC. So, for your example, I enter **Topic Aaa**. Then set the **Level** field to the outline level that I want the entry to have in the TOC. For this example, I've used the default value, **1**. Select **Mark**, and then select **Close**.

   The paragraph now contains the text `{ TC "Topic Aaa" \f C \l "1" }` with a dotted underline.
5. Add `\n` to the list of switches (for example, after `"1"`) to suppress page numbers when this entry is included in a TOC.
6. Copy all the inserted text, including the braces, and paste it into each successive **No Spacing** paragraph that I added, replacing `Topic Aaa` with the appropriate topic description each time.

   My document now looks like this.

   [image: Document with TC fields added]
7. In the **Styles** pane, select the drop-down arrow to the right of the style that I chose, and then select **Modify**. (Alternatively, right-click the style name, and then select **Modify**.)
8. In the **Modify Style** dialog box, on the **Format** drop-down menu in the lower-left corner, select **Frame**. I like to tuck these kinds of things out of the way in the left margin.
9. In the **Frame** dialog box, in the **Size** section, set the **Width** field to **Exactly**, and the **At** field to **72 pt** (because my example document is using Word's default 72-point left margin). In the **Horizontal** section, set the **Relative** to field to **Page**. Then select **OK**.

   Note: As a matter of personal preference, I like to change the font color (for example, to red) and reduce the font size for the paragraph style. This helps me make sure that I've applied the correct paragraph style to all the necessary paragraphs – and to no others. Since the text won't be visible in the finished document, this step is completely optional.

   When I select **OK**, my document looks like this.

   [image: Document after topic description paragraphs are styled]
10. On the **Home** tab of the ribbon, select the **Show/Hide ¶** button again to hide paragraph marks. Notice that there's no trace of the topic description paragraphs.

    [image: Document when paragraph marks are hidden]
11. Select the **Show/Hide ¶** button again to make paragraph marks visible.
12. Go to the place where I want to insert the TOC. Because I'll be inserting a custom TOC, I must manually enter the heading if I want one. So, for your example, I add a paragraph, type **Table of Contents**, and apply the **TOC Heading** paragraph style.
13. On the **References** tab of the ribbon, in the **Table of Contents** group, select **Table of Contents** > **Custom Table of Contents**.
14. In the **Table of Contents** dialog box, select **Options**.
15. In the **Table of Contents Options** dialog box, select the **Table entry fields** check box in the lower-right corner, so that Word will use the `TC` fields that I added when it builds the TOC. Then, because the topic paragraphs that I added were designated as outline level 1, I would adjust the numbers in the upper part of the dialog box, changing the **TOC level** value for **Heading 1** to **2**, changing the value for **Heading 2** to **3** (or deleting the value entirely if I don't want level-2 headings in the TOC), and so on. This step is useful if I decide that I want to make each level of the TOC visually distinct by modifying the **TOC1**, **TOC2**, etc., paragraph styles.

    [image: Table of Contents options dialog box]

    When I select **OK**, the TOC looks like this.

    [image: Table of Contents]

Again, when paragraph marks are hidden, the topic descriptions will be entirely hidden. They will also be hidden if I generate a PDF of the document. If you want to make sure that no one will see them, even if they have paragraph marks visible in Word, you can change the font color for the paragraph to white, maybe even reducing the font size to 1 pt. In addition, instead of using a frame, you could change the paragraph for the style so that it has a line height of exactly 1 point.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create multiple tocs for each of the set of chapters that are preceeded by the non heading headers as per you example.

So create the different tocs one at a time as described on this page [create multiple tocs](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010080_Using_Multiple_Tables_of_Contents.html)